How the get a list of types acceptable by a variable in TypeScript
I have an auto-generated file (from Proto not owned by me) that looks something like this:
export type Policy
    = UserPolicy
    | BrandPolicy
    | OrganizationPolicy;

const PolicyUnionFields = () => ({
});

export interface UserPolicy {
  readonly type: 'USER_POLICY';
  ...
}

export interface BrandPolicy {
  readonly type: 'BRAND_POLICY';
  ...
}

export interface OrganizationPolicy {
  readonly type: 'ORGANIZATION_POLICY';
  ...
}

I want to extract the list of all available interfaces that Policy can get. something like this:
['UserPolicy', 'BrandPolicy', 'OrganizationPolicy']

Since I don't own the proto, new interfaces can be added to Policy without notification.

"I want to extract the list of all available interfaces"... as an array of strings? For what purpose?

As asked, the answer is "you cannot do that". But why would you want to? What's the use case? This really seems like an XY problem where X is "extract interface names as strings, or as an array of strings" and Y is... what? What are you hoping to do with that array?  Maybe the use case can be satisfied in some other way.

If what you want is the type (compile-time) you can use:
type PolicyType = Policy['type']; // "USER_POLICY" | "BRAND_POLICY" | "ORGANIZATION_POLICY";

If you want these as an array at run-time. There are many ways you could achieve this, but the cleanest one I can think of is to use a decorators:
const IsPolicy = (policyName: Policy['type']) => (target: any, context: ClassDecoratorContext<any>): any => {
  let metadata: Set<Policy['type']> | undefined = (window as any)['__POLICIES'] || undefined;
  if (!metadata) {
    metadata = (window as any)['__POLICIES'] = new Set<Policy['type']>();
  }
  metadata.add(policyName);
  return target;
}

@IsPolicy('ORGANIZATION_POLICY')
class OrganizationPolicyImp implements OrganizationPolicy {
  public type: 'ORGANIZATION_POLICY' = 'ORGANIZATION_POLICY';
}

@IsPolicy('BRAND_POLICY')
class BrandPolicyImp implements BrandPolicy {
  public type: 'BRAND_POLICY' = 'BRAND_POLICY';
}

function getPolicies() {
  let metadata: Set<Policy['type']> | undefined = (window as any)['__POLICIES'] || undefined;
  return !metadata ? [] : Array.from(metadata);
}

console.log(getPolicies()); // ["ORGANIZATION_POLICY", "BRAND_POLICY"] 

I'm not sure of your use case, but the property public type might not be required if you use decorators. You could also change the Set for a Map where the key is the class (e.g. OrganizationPolicyImp or BrandPolicyImp) and the value is the policy name. Then you can create another function called getPolicyName(classConstructor: any) that takes the class (e.g. OrganizationPolicyImp or BrandPolicyImp) and returns the value passed to the decorator (e.g. "USER_POLICY" or "BRAND_POLICY". You could use this function instead of the property type to get the policy type for a class.

Please note that this implementation is not really robust; it is just a demo. The recommended approach would be to use https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorator-metadata
